Get Lightning Page Tab name by Id
I need to show Buttons in an LWC according to the visibility of some tabs for the current user. I show the respective button if the tab's visibility is 'DefaultOn'. If not, I don't show the button. The tab visibility is set as Available and Visible ('DefaultOn') on some Permission Sets that could be assigned or not to the user. I have been able to achieve this for most of the target tabs using the following code:
    Map<String, Boolean> permissions = new Map<String,Boolean>();
    Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    
    Set<String> psNames = new Set<String>{
        'MyPermissionSet1',
        'MyPermissionSet2',
        'MyPermissionSet3',
        'MyPermissionSet4',
        'MyPermissionSet5',
        'MyPermissionSet6',
        'MyPermissionSet7',
        'MyPermissionSet8',
        'MyPermissionSet9'
    };
    
    List<PermissionSetAssignment> psas= [
        SELECT Id, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.ProfileId, 
        PermissionSet.Profile.Name, AssigneeId, Assignee.Name 
        FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
        WHERE AssigneeId =: userId
        AND PermissionSet.Name IN :psNames
    ];
    
    List<Id> psIds = new List<Id>();
    for(PermissionSetAssignment psa : psas){
        psIds.add(psa.PermissionSetId);
    }

    List<PermissionSetTabSetting> psTabs = [
        SELECT Id, Name, Visibility
        FROM PermissionSetTabSetting
        WHERE ParentId IN :psIds
    ];
    
    Map<Id, String> mapTabIdVisibility = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(PermissionSetTabSetting psTab : psTabs){
        // Convert from 15 chars Id to 18 chars Id
        Id id18val = psTab.Name;
        // Add to map
        mapTabIdVisibility.put(id18val, psTab.Visibility);
    }
    
    // Get tab set describes for each app
    List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> allApps = Schema.describeTabs();

    // Iterate through each tab set describe for each app
    for (Schema.DescribeTabSetResult oneApp : allApps) {
        List<Schema.DescribeTabResult> appTabs = oneApp.getTabs();
        for(Schema.DescribeTabResult tab : appTabs){
            switch on tab.getName() {
                when 'My_tab_name_1', 'My_tab_name_2', 'My_tab_name_3', 'My_tab_name_4', 
                'My_tab_name_5', 'My_tab_name_6', 'My_tab_name_7', 'My_tab_name_8', 
                'My_tab_name_9', 'My_tab_name_10', 'My_tab_name_11', 'My_tab_name_12',
                'My_tab_name_13', 'My_tab_name_14', 'My_tab_name_15' {
                    // Get the visibility by the Id of the tab
                    if(mapTabIdVisibility.get(tab.getTabEnumOrId()) == 'DefaultOn'){
                        // Put the visibility of each tab
                        permissions.put(tab.getName(), true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.debug('permissions '+ permissions);

But there's an App Page created with Lightning App Builder. A Lightning Page Tab was created for this App Page. But this particular tab name does not appear on Schema.describeTabs(), so I can't verify if the user has access to it. How can I get the lightning page tab name, since I have already the Id of it?
